# Gridview stopped responding to onclick event after animation-ed to new position, old position still responds correctly

Tags: java, gridview, onclick, android-animation

I want to have an entry effect on my `gridview` menu, so I made a `gridview` with `imageView` and `textView` inside it, placed it OUTSIDE of the screen boundary, and on demand, an `animation` will play which brings it into the screen and visible to user and subsequently, the user can tap on it and perform various operations.

Now there's a problem: everything else appears to be in order except for the last part: I can play the `animation` correctly, the `gridView` menus is showing up properly as I had expected, but if I tap on it, nothing happens.

So I devised a simple scheme to see if it was caused by the fact that the `gridView` moved, but the `gridView` view stayed behind. What I did was that I placed the `gridView` inside the screen, then move it using `animation` to a new position.

And as expected, the `gridView`, after the `animation` is unresponsive, but if I click on where it once was, all `onclick` events are responding properly.

How shall I solve this most gracefully without rewriting a great deal of things?

Here is the (potentially) problematic code:

The gridview xml:

```
<GridView
    android:id="@+id/android_gridview_menu"
    android:layout_width="80dp"
    android:layout_height="0dp"

    android:background="#ffffff"


    app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintVertical_bias="0.0"
    app:layout_constraintLeft_toLeftOf="@id/CanvasView"
    android:layout_marginLeft="682dp"

    android:layout_marginTop="0dp"
    android:layout_marginBottom="0dp"
    >
```

the animation xml:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<set
xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:interpolator="@android:anim/linear_interpolator"
android:fillAfter="true">

<translate
    android:fromXDelta="100%"
    android:toXDelta="-146%"
    android:duration="300" />
</set>
```

code for gridview adapter:

```
public class CustomGridMenuAdaptor extends BaseAdapter {

private Context mContext;
private final String[] gridViewString;
private final int[] gridViewImageId;

public CustomGridMenuAdaptor(Context context, String[] gridViewString, int[] gridViewImageId) {
    mContext = context;
    this.gridViewImageId = gridViewImageId;
    this.gridViewString = gridViewString;
}

@Override
public int getCount() {
    return gridViewString.length;
}

@Override
public Object getItem(int i) {
    return null;
}

@Override
public long getItemId(int i) {
    return 0;
}

@Override
public View getView(int i, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
    View gridViewAndroid;
    LayoutInflater inflater = (LayoutInflater) mContext
            .getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);

    if (convertView == null) {

        gridViewAndroid = new View(mContext);
        gridViewAndroid = inflater.inflate(R.layout.android_custom_gridview_layout, null);
        TextView textViewAndroid = (TextView) gridViewAndroid.findViewById(R.id.android_gridview_text);
        ImageView imageViewAndroid = (ImageView) gridViewAndroid.findViewById(R.id.android_gridview_image);
        textViewAndroid.setText(gridViewString[i]);
        imageViewAndroid.setImageResource(gridViewImageId[i]);
    } else {
        gridViewAndroid = (View) convertView;
    }

    return gridViewAndroid;
}

}
```

Gridview menu on `clickListener` registeration

```
AdapterView.OnItemClickListener itemClickListener = new 
AdapterView.OnItemClickListener() {
        public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View v, int position, long id) {

            switch (position){
                case 0:
...
                    break;
}
```